# MySQL query with and without WHERE condition at once

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select both values at once? For example, I have a Lesson that have Students and each Student is linked to a Client, so what I want to achieve is something like:

```
SELECT l.id, 
       l.value * clientStudents/totalStudents as total 
FROM Lesson l 
JOIN lesson_student ls ON l.id = ls.lesson_id 
JOIN Student s ON ls.student_id = s.id 
JOIN Client c ON s.client_id = c.id 
**WHERE c.id = <SOME_CLIENT>**
```

being clientStudents the count using the WHERE clause and totalStudents without using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the condition in the calculation phase. Something like:

```
SELECT l.id, 
       l.value * SUM(if(c.id = <SOME_CLIENT>,clientStudents,0)) / SUM(totalStudents) as total 
FROM Lesson l 
JOIN lesson_student ls ON l.id = ls.lesson_id 
JOIN Student s ON ls.student_id = s.id 
JOIN Client c ON s.client_id = c.id
GROUP BY l.id, l.value
```

Comment: Thanks Parkyprg. Is there any way to avoid passing the Client id? What I'm doing is summing the total sales (SUM(total)) for each Client (GROUP BY c.id). So the real interest is for example Lesson 1 have 2 Students of Client 1 and 1 Student of Client 2, it calculates for Client 1 l.value * 2/3 and for Client 2 l.value * 1/3.

Comment: If it's useful to someone what I did was to use 2 sub queries, each one to select the desired count, but it was so heavy that I've created a new Table relating Lesson and Client with a weight field.